# Laravel MySQL JSON LIKE Query

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.6, mysql-5.7

In laravel using eloquent I can use LIKE query like this:

```
Model::where('column', 'LIKE', 'a%');
```

That query the column that starts with letter a. How can I do it in a json column?.

```
Model::where('meta->column', 'LIKE', 'a%');
```

I tried it but not getting any result where querying it like this:

```
Model::where('meta->column', 'LIKE', '%a%');
```

Returns a result where column contains letter a. I only want to query the column where it starts with letter a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, the result of `meta->column` is JSON encoded. You have to add the leading quote:

```
Model::where('meta->column', 'LIKE', '"a%');
```

In Laravel 5.6.28 you can use the [`->>` operator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24817):

```
Model::where('meta->>column', 'LIKE', 'a%');
```

Comment: This is awesome. I never knew this existed before.

Comment: Keep in mind that this operates case-sensitive, regardless of your schema or table's charset/collation. I could only find 1 ugly solution for case-insensitive like on a json column:
->whereRaw('LOWER(meta->"$.column") like ?', '%'.strtolower('a').'%'))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this' going to work but you might give it a shot. It uses MySQL 8 [JSON search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html).

```
Model::where(DB::raw('meta->"$.column" LIKE "%a%"'))->get();
```